# how to show all image in jsp page from particular folder?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I have one folder it contain more then one images, i want to show all image in my jsp page. I try following code in my jsp page.

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/uploadFolder/poll1.jpg"
      width="114" height="110" style="float: left;">
<h1>
   Images
</h1>
```

I have more then 10 images in uploadFolder i want to display all images in jsp page kindly help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File f = new File("/uploadFolder/");

File[] list = f.listFiles();
```

You will get list of all files in your upload folder -

You just need to loop through it like this -

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++){
  File jpg = list[i]; 
  // use this file object to create img tag's in your jsp
}
```

More info about [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: how to write file in jsp page? please provide full code with syntax i dont know how to write

Answer (score 1):

use following code on your jsp page :

```
File folder = new File("d:\\Reports"); //your path
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
{
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
    {
```

in html page:

```
<a href="servlet&filename=<%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%>">Download</a> 


}}
```

i have shown using `<a>` tag you can show it in table or in `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Build the list of filenames to display.

```
List imageUrlList = new ArrayList();  
File imageDir = new File("/myapp/images");  
for(File imageFile : imageDir.listFiles()){  
  String imageFileName = imageFile.getName();  

  // add this images name to the list we are building up  
  imageUrlList.add(imageFileName);  

}  
request.setAttribute("imageUrlList", imageUrlList);
```

then on the jsp display an `<img>` tag for each file.

```
<c:forEach var="img" items="${imageUrlList}">  
  <img >  
</c:forEach>
```